# select2 option showing in wrong position

Tags: css, vue.js, jquery-select2

I am using select2 for drop-down option. But it is showing in the wrong position.
Here is my code:

```vue
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span v-bind:style="{ width: prependWidth + 'px' }" class="input-group-text">Select Heading</span>
        </div>
        <select class="form-control select2" v-model="formData.heading_id" id="heading_id"
                name="heading_id" required>
            <option :key="'heading_id'" value="">Select Heading</option>
            <option v-for="(heading, index) in headings" :key="'heading_id' + index" :value="heading.id">
                training year @{{ heading.training_year }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label v-if="errors.heading_id" class="help-block text-danger" style="margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 0; padding: 0;">
        @{{ errors.heading_id[0] }}
    </label>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.select2').select2();
    });
</script>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try to paste the code a little more carefully, because you paste it with errors that make reading difficult.

Comment: It seems to me that you use the same ID for many components and that is the problem. Paste an example of already rendered code, 2-3 rows.

Comment: If you have more than one select2 initialized in your code, post all of them as a working snippet. Help us to help you.